# How to change background color for some cell in WPF DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a datagrid binded to an object collection.

One property of the objects is a string that store a color value.

[image: my dataGrid]

On this "COLORBACKGROUND" cell click, a colorpicker opens to change it.

What I need is to change the background color of the cell by the value displayed in datagrid rows (#RGB).

```
<DataGrid SelectionUnit="Cell" SelectedCellsChanged="DgDataTable_OnSelectedCellsChanged" x:Name="DgDataTable" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="10,20,10,0" AutoGenerateColumns="true" HeadersVisibility="All" RowHeaderWidth="20" Style="{StaticResource AzureDataGrid}" GridLinesVisibility="Horizontal" LoadingRow="dgDataTable_LoadingRow" ColumnHeaderHeight="10" AlternatingRowBackground="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GradientActiveCaptionBrushKey}}" AutoGeneratingColumn="DgDataTable_AutoGeneratingColumn">
    <DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRowHeader">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="10"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightCyan"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>
    <DataGrid.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Center"/>
          <!--  <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Text" Value="John">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers> -->
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.CellStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

I tried something with AutoGenerating column :

```
private void DgDataTable_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == "SrcAlert")
    {
        DataGridComboBoxColumn cb = new DataGridComboBoxColumn();
        e.Column = cb;
        cb.ItemsSource = new List<string> {"1", "2"};
        cb.SelectedValueBinding = new Binding("SrcAlert");
        e.Column.Header = "SrcAlert";
    }
    if (e.PropertyName.Equals("ColorBackground"))
    {
        DataGridTextColumn tc = new DataGridTextColumn();
        e.Column = tc;
        tc.Foreground = (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(DgDataTable.CurrentCell.Item.ColorBackground);
    }
}
```

this `Item.ColorBackground` doesn't compile... I put it for my explanation, thats what I need.

I tried another solution I found :

```
if (e.PropertyName.Equals("ColorBackground"))
{
    string s = DgDataTable.CurrentCell.Item.ToString();
    e.Column.CellStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(DataGridCell.BackgroundProperty, (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(s)));
}
```

but that was a fail.

Thank you for your help !

---

Edit : A screenshot of ASh solution that works perfectly for me:

[image]

---

EDIT : I adapted your solution for multiple columns with color Picker :

[image]

I add style setters to display only colors in the cells :

```
    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell" x:Key="ColorPickerCellBG" 
       BasedOn="{StaticResource CommonCell}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Path=BG}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="30"></Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell" x:Key="ColorPickerCellAL" 
       BasedOn="{StaticResource CommonCell}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Path=AL}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="30"></Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style...
```

When the cell is clicked, the rgb color value is visible, the style must be "ClickedCell"...
How can I Improve that ?

Comment: what is the meaning of  < What I need is to change the background color of the cell by the value displayed in datagrid rows (#RGB). >

Comment: Instead of displaying "#556677" in the cell, I'd like that it's background color be this one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it is possible to apply special style to a single auto-generated column.

declare two cell styles in resources

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell" x:Key="CommonCell"
           BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridCell}}">
        <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell" x:Key="ColorPickerCell" 
           BasedOn="{StaticResource CommonCell}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Path=ColorBackground}"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

`ColorPickerCell` inherits `CommonCell` style.

```
<DataGrid SelectionUnit="Cell" 
          x:Name="DgDataTable" 
          AutoGenerateColumns="true" HeadersVisibility="All" RowHeaderWidth="20" 
          GridLinesVisibility="Horizontal" 
          ColumnHeaderHeight="10" 
          AlternatingRowBackground="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GradientActiveCaptionBrushKey}}" 

          CellStyle="{StaticResource CommonCell}"
          AutoGeneratingColumn="DgDataTable_AutoGeneratingColumn">

    <DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRowHeader">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="10"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightCyan"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>

</DataGrid>
```

change `CellStyle` for a generated column:

```
private void DgDataTable_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == "ColorBackground")
    {
        e.Column.CellStyle = (sender as DataGrid).FindResource("ColorPickerCell") as Style;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah ! A simple and elegant solution ASh. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Apply a `Converter`, this `Converter` is used for two diff. purpose hence returns two diff types. Beauty of this approach is : You can change the `property` in `XAML` itself. No change needed in code now, and hence it is MVVM friendly.

For example, in `DataTrigger` change `Value=BkgProp` to `Value=Name` and see.

Sample XAML :

```
<Window ...>
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:PropBasedStringToColorConverter x:Key="StringToColorCnvKey"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="Dgrd">
        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding .Column, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource StringToColorCnvKey}}" Value="BkgProp">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding BkgProp, Converter={StaticResource StringToColorCnvKey}}"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>                    
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.Resources>
    </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Sample Data :

```
Dgrd.ItemsSource = new[] { new { BkgProp = "#abcdef", Name = "Anjum" }, new { BkgProp = "#edf2ed", Name = "Anjum" }, new { BkgProp = "#ff0000", Name = "Anjum" } }.ToList();
```

Converter Code :

```
public class PropBasedStringToColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        object result = null;

        if (value == null) return "N/A";

        if (value.GetType() == typeof(DataGridTextColumn))
        { 
            string path = ((Binding)((DataGridTextColumn)value).Binding).Path.Path;
            return path;
        }
        else if (value.GetType() == typeof(string))
        {
            result = new SolidColorBrush((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(value.ToString()));
        }
        return result;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response AnjumSKhan.

Comment: I forgot to check for a particular column, sorry !

Comment: @Alexus Please see the updated answer now, you can just change the property name in XAML itself to change `Column` at will. `Converter` code will remain same. No change needed in code now.